# Replace <p> </p> with <br /> with condition

Tags: php, jquery, regex, preg-replace

In wordpress I am outputting some `<div>`s along the content of my shortcode. The problem is because wordpress puts paragraphs inside `<p></p>` tags, the line is broken where the `<div>` is.
What I want to achieve is to replace `<p> </p>` which surrounds my shortcode with `<br />`. 
For example, if my content looks like this:

```
<p>[shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text<br />
[shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text<br />
text<br />
text [shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text </p>
<p>text<br />
text [shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text<br />
text</p>
<p> text without shortcode </p>
<p>text [shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text </p>
```

I need it to convert it in

```
<br/>[shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text<br />
[shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text<br />
text<br />
text [shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text <br />
<br/>text<br />
text [shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text<br />
text<br/>
<p> text without shortcode </p>
<br/>text [shortcodes attr='somethig']value[/shortcode] text <br/>
```

I tried to solve the problem by myself, but my preg_replace expression was capturing the whole content, instead of individual `<p> </p>` blocks.

<strike>Solutions with jQuery are alright too (but instead of shortcode, a `<div>` with a specific class must be contained in the paragraph)</strike>

LE: The following jQuery worked. However, I am still waiting for a more elegant solution in PHP.

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().find('.measurement_value').length > 0) 
    {
        $(this).replaceWith(  '<br />' + $(this).html());
    }
});
```

Comment: "wordpress puts paragraphs inside `<p></p>` tags" ???

Comment: This is something that should be solved on the serverside _before_ the content is outputted.

Comment: This is what I was trying to achieve in PHP, filtering the content ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this jquery code :

```
$('p').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('.class-of-the-div').length > 0) {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html() + '<br />');
    }
});
```

But, normally, Wordpress replace `<br />` with `<p></p>` on server side.

Comment: Thanks, but this partially helps me. I want to replace only the paragraphs which contain a div with a certain class, not all of the paragraphs.

Comment: Since the paragraph was closing automatically in the DOM before the div, the following code worked:
`$('p').each(function() {
  if ($(this).next().find('.measurement_value').length > 0) 
  {
   $(this).replaceWith(  '<br />' + $(this).html());
  }
 });`
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just get rid of `<p>` by adding `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');` in functions.php

Comment: I am developing a plugin, and I try to avoid as much as possible solutions with effects on the whole site. In addition to that, the post gets clutterd :)